# IOS/OCUnit STAssertThrows - link to documentation & example of how to use?

Tags: iphone, ios, ocunit

anyone have a link or two to the IOS / OCUnit documentation for "STAssertThrows"

The API doco + an example of how to use would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here are the docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/AB-Unit-Test_Result_Macro_Reference/result_macro_reference.html)

Usage is fairly straight forward, say you have a method

```
-(void)foo {
  [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"always thrown"];
}
```

Then this assertion will always pass

```
-(void)testFoo {
    STAssertThrows([obj foo], @"should throw an exception");
}
```

You will probably want to use `STAssertThrowsSpecific` or `STAssertThrowsSpecificNamed` instead since you might run into hard to catch bugs if you just catch any exception.